# Omnet++ 5.1 preview 2 Error

Tags: c++, simulator, omnet++, inet

I have installed (without any error) OMNeT++ version 5.1 preview 2 on Windows 10.

I don't know where is the problem but I cannot run any simulation. I tried the tictoc example. I built it and the run it, this is the output from the console:

```
Starting...

$ cd C:/omnetpp-5.1pre2/samples/tictoc
$ tictoc.exe -m -u Qtenv omnetpp.ini

Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741511
Working directory: C:/omnetpp-5.1pre2/samples/tictoc
Command line: tictoc.exe -m -u Qtenv omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;C:/omnetpp-5.1pre2/ide/jre/bin/server;C:/omnetpp-5.1pre2/ide/jre/bin;C:/omnetpp-5.1pre2/ide/jre/lib/amd64;.;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\usr\local\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\usr\bin\site_perl;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\tools\win64\usr\bin\core_perl;C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2;
OMNETPP_ROOT=C:/omnetpp-5.1pre2/
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=C:\omnetpp-5.1pre2\images
```

The same happens with every other example.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean and rebuild OMNeT and its examples?

When you start the mingw.cmd, type:

```
make cleanall
./configure
make -j2
```

-j2 is to parallelize the compilation process. You can adjust it to the number of CPU cores that you have available.

If the examples still do not run, try to change the compiler from Clang to GCC.

Edit the "configure.user" file in the "omnetpp-5.1pre2" directory and change the line (number 21):

```
PREFER_CLANG=yes
```

and change it to

```
PREFER_CLANG=no
```

Then again:

```
make cleanall
./configure
make -j2
```

Afterwards, you can try again. All the executable should be built via GCC, in case your error is related to Clang issues.

Comment: Error is still there

Comment: Did you run your simulation in the debug mode? At which point in the source code does the error occur exactly?